# Incrementar letras no PHP?

Tags: php, loop, tipagem

Recentemente precisei incrementar letras no PHP dentro de um laço de repetição.

Para cada iteração, ao invés de índices numéricos, precisava de letras do alfabeto.

Daí, como já sei que o PHP faz incrementação de letras (e por ser bem simples), eu fiz algo parecido com isso.

```
for($letra = 'a'; $letra != 'aa'; $letra++) {

    echo $letra;
}

// abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
```

Porém, pelo fato de nunca ter visto isso documentado e nem em nenhuma outra linguagem que eu conheço uma funcionalidade como essa, fiquei na dúvida se deveria utilizar ou não.

Por conta de codificação (e entre outros), é seguro utilizar esse recurso, ou é melhor apelar para os amigos `chr` ou o `range('a', 'z')`, como no exemplo abaixo?

```
for($letra = 97; $letra <= 122; $letra++) {

    echo chr($letra);
}

//abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz


echo implode('', range('a', 'z')); //abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz

//abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Isso é típico de linguagem fracamente tipadas, como C por exemplo. Um tipo pode ser usado como se fosse outro. Note que isso é diferente de ser dinamicamente tipado, tanto que C é estaticamente tipada (e se comporta um pouco diferente).

À princípio não há problemas. Não causa erros de nenhum tipo. Apenas recomenda-se evitar essa característica quando é possível porque é fácil **usar** errado. Claro que em situações simples como esta é difícil errar.

Se é possível dizer explicitamente qual é a intenção (trabalhar com caracteres) é um pouco melhor do ponto de vista de legibilidade. Quem não conhece esta característica pode estranhar o primeiro código da pergunta. Mas dizer que está errado é preciosismo.

Eu sei que é apenas um exemplo, mas neste caso eu usaria mesmo é uma *string* literal :)

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Difícil foi descobrir que depois do `'z'` vem o `'aa'`, kkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkk

Comment: Pra falar a verdade isso também me surpreendeu. Isso é invencionice do PHP. Pode parecer prático e está coerente com o que o PHP faz mas do ponto de visto do computador isto não faz muito sentido.

Comment: Tecnicamente faz sentido sim, pense em base hexadecimal-like. O `a` seria o número 1 e o `z` seria `maiorValor-1`. O próximo número seria 'a0'. Como o `0` não existe, usa-se o `a` mesmo.

Answer (score 4):

Como já foi falado, isso é característica de linguagens fracamente tipadas. isso funciona porque incremento é feito no código `ASCII(A-Z 65-90, a-z 97-122)`, e não exatamente na letra que você vê. Isso funciona apenas com operador de incremento(`++`). Já com o de decremento não é possível, ou seja, não dá para criar uma string de z-a Z-A.

O [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.increment.php) fala desse comportamento, que ele segue a convesão [Perl](https://www.perl.org/) que diz que o conjunto válido para o incremento é (a-z, A-Z e 0-9), por isso `z` vira `aa`, no C ele seguiria o próximo código ASCII.

Essa funcionalidade é útil ao montar o cabeçalho de uma planilha onde as coordenadas são ex: `A1, B1 ...`

Exemplos em Perl

```
$char = 'z';
print ++$char; //saída: aa
```

Exemplo equivalente do [range()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.range.php)

```
@alfabeto = ('a'..'z');

foreach(@alfabeto){
    print $_
}
```

Answer (score 0):

É normal fazer desta forma, se eu fosse necessitar de uma solução assim eu faria desta forma:

```
foreach (range('a', 'z') as $letra) {
   print $letra;
}
```