# Como encurtar o processo de criar um array sem a necessidade de escrever todos os índices?

Tags: php, array

Por exemplo, se eu precisar criar uma array com 20 espaços, eu preciso fazer sempre dessa forma?

```
$teste = array(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,18,19);
```

Ou tem alguma forma de encurtar esse processo, esse 0 ao 19?

Algo do tipo: `$teste = array(0..19);`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Pode criar um array com determinadas posições usando a função [`range()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.range.php).

O primeiro argumento é número que deve começar o primeiro elemento e o segundo o valor máximo. Caso o valor valor máximo seja menor que o valor inicia o array será gerado de forma decrecente.

Ainda existe um terceiro argumento ao ser passado ele determina qual deve ser o intervalo entre os valores o padrão é um.

```
$teste = range(0, 5);
```

Saida:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 0
    [1] => 1
    [2] => 2
    [3] => 3
    [4] => 4
    [5] => 5
)
```

**[Exemplo - ideone](http://ideone.com/zKqmFy)**

**Relacionada:**

[Incrementar letras no PHP?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/49449/91)

Comment: Ai funciona da mesma forma? $teste[1] = "Teste"; Até o 5?

Comment: @LucasCarvalho ele vai preencher os valores do array com o 'inicio' e o 'fim' especificados. vc quer que o valor seja fixo?

Comment: Entendi rray, ele vai fazer sim o que quero :) Muito obrigado!

Comment: @LucasCarvalho outras opções para iniciar um array são as funções: [array_pad](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-pad.php), [array_fill](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-fill.php) e [array_fill_keys](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-fill-keys.php). Para cada caso uma ou outra se adequa melhor a situação.

Comment: Vou estudar elas, procurar mais! Não sabia delas. Obrigado!

Answer (score 8):

Você pode utilizar a função [array_fill](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-fill.php), esta função retorna um array preenchido.

```
$meuArray = array_fill(0, 20, NULL);
```

Onde neste array todos os espaços serão preenchidos por null.