# Montar listagem de A-Z em PHP

Tags: php

Preciso fazer um form select de A-Z, como eu posso fazer isto sem ser manualmente? Neste caso, eu faria manualmente da seguinte forma:

```
<select>
     <option>A</option>
     <option>B</option>
     <option>Z</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Não entendi porque me negativaram, era uma dúvida minha e a resposta dele foi exata!

Comment: Relacioanda: [Incrementar letras no PHP?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/49449/91)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Aqui está espero que o ajude:

```
foreach (range('A', 'Z') as $char) {
   echo $char . "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Só para complementar a resposta do `life.cpp`

Uma boa alternativa é utilizar o foreach. Mas como fazer uma repetição, se o foreach trabalha com um array existente?

O PHP nos fornece a função `range()` que cria um array conforme os parâmetros por nós definidos.

`range ( "inicio" , "fim" [, N ] )`, onde N, opcional, é um numero que define o numero de passos. Se omitido assume o valor 1, ou seja, todos os elementos serão elencados.

Exemplo 1 - : `$y = range("a", "z");`  [**veja no ideone**](https://ideone.com/NNNrgB)

Exemplo 2 - : `$y = range("a", "z" , 2);`  [**veja no ideone**](https://ideone.com/u69t1r)

**Outra forma é conforme**  [**esse exemplo no ideone**](https://ideone.com/gxRWil)

[**Para fazer testes da função range on line**](https://pt.functions-online.com/range.html)